# How can I promisify google api requests?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, promise

I have grouped addresses. I take one and create a request to google API but I don't execute this request I push to an array for next Promise.all this requests. I guess "googleMapsClient.directions" don't return promise.
How to collect and execute all requests with Promise.all?

```
    urlsPromises.push(
    googleMapsClient.directions({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: waypoints,
        optimize: true,
        mode: 'driving'
    }));
});
console.log(urlsPromises); 
// return: 
// [ { cancel: [Function], finally: [Function] },
// { cancel: [Function], finally: [Function] } ]

Promise.all(urlsPromises).then(results => {
    results.forEach((route, index1) => {
        const tripIndex = index1;
        console.log('- RESULT');
        //result: 
        // - RESULT
        //   [ { cancel: [Function], finally: [Function] },
        //   { cancel: [Function], finally: [Function] } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly create a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object by doing something like this:

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do what you need here
  if(something) {
    resolve(someValue)
  } else {
    reject(someError)
  }
});
```

You could even wrap a request and `resolve`/`reject` after its completion handling the results before.

Comment: Oh, great idea. I will try this.

Comment: Great, you make my day!